# Display arrays in same order with whitespaces

Tags: php

I'm having problems display two arrays with concrete structure, I don't know if is possible..
I have 2 arrays multidimensional

### $a

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array 
( [id] => 1
  [total] => 4 
  [label] => one 
  [url] => 0 )

[1] => Array 
( [id] => 2
  [total] => 2 
  [label] => two 
  [url] => 500 ) 

[2] => Array 
( [id] => 3
  [total] => 9 
  [label] => three 
  [url] => -100 ) 

[3] => Array 
( [id] => 5
  [total] => 15 
  [label] => five 
  [ten] => 100 ) 
)
```

### $b

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array 
( [id] => 1
  [total] => 2 
  [label] => one 
  [url] => 100 )

[1] => Array 
( [id] => 4
  [total] => 4 
  [label] => four 
  [url] => -100 ) 

[2] => Array 
( [id] => 3
  [total] => 1 
  [label] => three 
  [url] => 200 ) 

[3] => Array 
( [id] => 5
  [total] => 1 
  [label] => five 
  [ten] => -100 ) 
) 

[4] => Array 
( [id] => 7
  [total] => 1 
  [label] => seven 
  [ten] => 500 ) 
) 

[5] => Array 
( [id] => 6
  [total] => 1 
  [label] => six 
  [ten] => 200 ) 
)
```

And I want this structure listing arrays by label

```
$a      $b
---     ---
one     one
two     -
three   three
-       four
five    five
-       six
-       seven
```

It's possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: without having any numeric id or something i think its really hard to achive  this. may be have an array of number(like one,tow,three) and latter use that array to check

Comment: I can have a id unique, post edited. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to sort the array by `id` value using [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) like that

```
    // Define an test array
    $array = array(
        0 => array(
            "id" => 1,
            "total" => 4,
            "label" => "one",
            "url" => 0
        ),
        1 => array(
            "id" => 7,
            "total" => 10,
            "label" => "seven",
            "url" => 0
        ),
        2 => array(
            "id" => 2,
            "total" => 13,
            "label" => "two",
            "url" => 0
        )
    );

    // Get a "id" list from the array
    $ids = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
        $ids[$key]  = $row['id'];
    }
```

Result :

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => int 1
      'total' => int 4
      'label' => string 'one' (length=3)
      'url' => int 0
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => int 2
      'total' => int 13
      'label' => string 'two' (length=3)
      'url' => int 0
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => int 7
      'total' => int 10
      'label' => string 'seven' (length=5)
      'url' => int 0
```

For the display, we need just a loop and check if the node with `$findIdNode["id"] == $i` exist.

```
   // Display the result
    for($i=1; $i<=end($array)["id"]; $i++) {
        // Check if the "id" value exist in $array
        $findIdNode = $array[array_search($i, array_column($array, "id"))];
        if($findIdNode["id"] == $i)
            echo $findIdNode["label"]."<br />";
        else
            echo "-<br />";
    }
```

Result :

```
one
two
-
-
-
-
seven
```

Hope it will help.